throw new GoogleGenerativeAIFetchError
i'm trying to make an application like bolt using google gemini, now im having issue that im getting this error whenever i hit request from postman to my code.
pls i need ur help, thank you
throw new GoogleGenerativeAIFetchError(`Error fetching from ${url.toString()}: [${response.status} ${response.statusText}] ${message}`, response.status, response.statusText, errorDetails);
          ^

GoogleGenerativeAIFetchError: [GoogleGenerativeAI Error]: Error fetching from https://generativelanguage.googleapis.com/v1beta/models/gemini-1.5-pro:streamGenerateContent?alt=sse: [400 Bad Request] Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "content" at 'contents[0].parts[0]': Cannot find field. [{"@type":"type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.BadRequest","fieldViolations":[{"field":"contents[0].parts[0]","description":"Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"content\" at 'contents[0].parts[0]': Cannot find field."}]}]
    at handleResponseNotOk (C:\Users\dell\OneDrive\Desktop\BOLT\be\node_modules\@google\generative-ai\dist\index.js:414:11)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async makeRequest (C:\Users\dell\OneDrive\Desktop\BOLT\be\node_modules\@google\generative-ai\dist\index.js:387:9)
    at async generateContentStream (C:\Users\dell\OneDrive\Desktop\BOLT\be\node_modules\@google\generative-ai\dist\index.js:827:22) {
  status: 400,
  statusText: 'Bad Request',
  errorDetails: [
    {
      '@type': 'type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.BadRequest',
      fieldViolations: [
        {
          field: 'contents[0].parts[0]',
          description: `Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "content" at 'contents[0].parts[0]': Cannot find field.`
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}

Node.js v20.12.2

i tried my best to change the code or solve the error, but this error is killing me

please exit your question and include [example]
